# Azure Data Factory - How to disable a pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory that I would like to publish, however I want to delay one of the pipelines from running as it uses a shared resource that isn't quite ready.

If possible I would like to allow the previous pipelines to run and then enable the downstream pipeline when the resource is ready for it.

How can I disable a pipeline so that I can re-enable it at a later time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really possible in ADF directly. However, I think you have a couple of options to dealing with this.

**Option 1.**

Chain the datasets in the activities to enforce a fake dependency making the second activity wait. This is a bit clunky and requires the provisioning of fake datasets. But could work.

**Option 2.**

Manage it at a higher level with something like PowerShell.

For example:

Use the following cmdlet to check the status of the first activity and wait maybe in some sort of looping process.

```
Get-​Azure​Rm​Data​Factory​Activity​Window
```

Next, use the following cmdlet to pause/unpause the downstream pipeline as required.

```
Suspend-​Azure​Rm​Data​Factory​Pipeline
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Edit your trigger and make sure Activated is checked NO. And of course don't forget to publish your changes!

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to *publish* the change after authoring!! Elsewhere the pipeline will continue to be triggered

Answer (score 1):

1. You mentioned publishing, so if you are publishing trough Visual Studio, it is possible to disable a pipeline by setting its property "isPaused" to true in .json pipeline configuration file.

[Property for making pipeline paused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Phh.png)

2. You can disable pipeline by clicking Monitor & Manage in Data Factory you are using. Then click on the pipeline and in the upper left corner you have two options:

   - Pause: Will not terminate current running job, but will not start next
   - Terminate: Terminates all job instances (as well as not starting future ones)

[GUI disabling pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyxih.png)

(TIP: Paused and Terminated pipeline have orange color, resumed have green color)

3. Use the powershell cmdlet to check the status of the activity

   Get-​Azure​Rm​Data​Factory​Activity​Window

Use the powershell cmdlet to pause/unpause a pipeline as required.

```
Suspend-​Azure​Rm​Data​Factory​Pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the pipeline in the "Monitor and Manage" application and select "Pause Pipeline".

Comment: I was about to post a better answer. I got the impression you wanted to manage this programmatically??

Comment: At the moment, I'm just looking for an easy fix as it's a bit of a one off project, but you answer is far more complete!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using ADF V2 and your pipeline is scheduled to run using a trigger, check which trigger your pipeline uses. Then go to the Manage tab and click on Author->Triggers. There you will get an option to stop the trigger. Publish the changes once you've stopped the trigger.